# Should pot files (gettext) be in version control?

Tags: gettext

I am new to gettext.

I see that there are some projects which keep pot files in version control.

But this creates huge changes, where nothing has changed:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openteachermaintainers/openteacher/3.x/revision/757

Is this good practice?

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 3):

The .pot files should not be in your version control, as it's fully auto generated at build (or should be at least). The .po files on the other hand should be a part of your version control, those contain the actual translations.

To avoid this, properly set up you build system to generate these files. See http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/gettext.html if you're using automake.